# Upload larger files using heroku

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3

I have hosted my code on heroku and using S3 to upload files. Everything is working correctly but upload of larger files fails. On researching i found it maybe because of heroku 30s timeout.Now we need to have server response every 30s how should i achieve it.There is a plugin called Plupload but i am not user if it can be integrated with python properly. Is there another way so i can store urls  in model and files in S3. I am using Dropzone.js in frontend to facilitate ajax.

**settings.py**

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='xxx'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='xxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'


AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN='xxx.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'

STATIC_URL = "http://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'


MEDIA_URL = "http://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
```

**template**

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">
<form action="{% url 'harpoons:upload' %}"
      class="dropzone"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def youmaterial(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        newdoc = Youmaterial(docfile = request.FILES['file'],user=request.user)
        newdoc.save()
        msg='dee'
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': msg}))

    else:
        form1 = DocumentForm()
    return render(request,'mat_upload.html',{'form':form1})
```